# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined (ionic 3.9 , Angularjs 5.0.3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to ionic. I want to access the data through an API key, but I got an error like this:

> Runtime Error : Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot read property 'create' 
>     of undefined
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
>       at new SamplePage (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1143:41)
>       at createClass (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12521:20)
>       at createDirectiveInstance (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12364:37)
>       at createViewNodes (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13802:53)
>       at createRootView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13692:5)
>       at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15093:42)
>       at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] 
>       (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14394:12)
>       at ComponentFactory_.create (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:11313:46)
>       at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create 
>       (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4275:29)
>       at NavControllerBase._viewInit 
>       (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:51546:44)
>       at c (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19752)
>       at Object.reject (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19174)
>       at NavControllerBase._fireError 
>       (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:51328:16)
>       at NavControllerBase._failed 
>       (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:51321:14)
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:51368:59
>       at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14976)
>       at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4982:33)
>       at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14916)
>       at r.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10143)
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20242

sample.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpProvider } from '../../providers/http/http';
import { NavController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/**
* Generated class for the SamplePage page.
 *
* See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info 
   on
* Ionic pages and navigation.
*/

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-sample',
    templateUrl: 'sample.html',
    providers: [HttpProvider]
})
export class SamplePage {
    newsData: any;
    loading: any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams:
        NavParams, private httpProvider: HttpProvider) {
        this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
            content: `
      <ion-spinner ></ion-spinner>`
        });
        this.getdata();
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad SamplePage');
    }
    getdata() {
        this.httpProvider.getJsonData().subscribe(
            result => {
                this.newsData = result.data.children;
                console.log("Success : " + this.newsData);
            },
            err => {
                console.error("Error : " + err);
            },
            () => {
                console.log('getData completed');
            }
        );
    }
}
```

sample.html

```
 <ion-header>
     <ion-navbar>
         <ion-title>sample</ion-title>
     </ion-navbar>
 </ion-header>
 <ion-content padding>
     <ion-list >
         <ion-item text-wrap *ngFor="let item of newsData" >
             <p >{{item.data.title}}</p>
         </ion-item>
     </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
```

In Provider folder 
http.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

/*
Generated class for the HttpProvider provider.

See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on 
providers
and Angular DI.
   */
@Injectable()
export class HttpProvider {
    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        console.log('Hello HttpProvider Provider');
    }
    getJsonData() {
        return this.http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/.json').map(r es 
            => res.json());
    }
}
```

I don't know how to overcome this. Could anyone please give me some ideas?

Comment: What is the use of `loadingCtrl` . I couldn't see any variable initialization  for `loadingCtrl`.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed initializing loadingCtrl as LoadingController to the constructor and hence it does not have access to create property of LoadingController :

```
constructor(private loadingCtrl: LoadingController)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @ Mahesh , it cleared that error but now it shows typescript error , can you please help me                                                      
      
 Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'.               
                                               





 getJsonData(){
          return  
 this.http.get('xxxxxx'').map(res => res.json());
}

Comment: console.log(res) and see in what format is the response.

Comment: try subscribing this.http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/.json').subscribe(res => console.log(res));  //the response is in json format

Comment: yeah i tried this , am already write subscribe in sample.ts show it shows some error
    ** `/sample.ts, line: 39
            Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'. Did you mean 'unsubscribe'?`**

Comment: oh ok i missed it. ok then just try returning you will get the json data inside your subscribe.   getJsonData() {
    return this.http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/.json')
  }     and in sample.ts   this.httpProvider.getJsonData().subscribe(result=>{
      console.log(result);
    }) // you will get result.data.children and children is an array from which you could get your desired data

Comment: @MeenaArumugam If you found this kind of error, then you need import that modules as well.

Comment: @Mahesh  your suggestion clear my error, but it shows nothing even console.log syntax is given

Comment: kindly please check my code , if I missed any imports ? @RameshRajendran

Comment: @MeenaArumugam sorry i did not understand what do you get in you console does it log the retrieved data

Comment: i just used your api and tried i am able to get the result its in json format which has result.data.children .guess you missing something very basic and  you have to wait till you get the response from the server it takes some time

Comment: @MeenaArumugam just check my answer which i gave first i have attached a picture

Answer (score 0):

Please additionally  add this below modules in your both components (service and controller)

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```